# ASP.NET Core 6 Self Hosted Windows Service without IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do you self-host an ASP.NET Core 6 Minimal API application as a Windows Service?
Everything works when the exe is executed, but having problems deploying to a production server as a Windows Service so that the app restarts automatically after a reboot.  I would like to avoid using IIS if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was able use the workaround provided by Michael Goll in this answer related to the .NET 6 Preview version:  [ASP.NET Core .NET 6 Preview 7 Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69124310/asp-net-core-net-6-preview-7-windows-service)